# Eclipse startup error: "Could not create the Java Virtual Machine"

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I'm using the latest version of Eclipse, labeled 2022-06. I haven't been able to get the installer (eclipse-inst-jre-win64.exe) to work, so I have downloaded the zip file (eclipse-java-indigo-win32-x86_64.zip), and manually copied the zipped "eclipse" folder to c:\Exclipse\eclipse. When I doubleclick on eclipse.exe, I get a dialog box entitled: "Java Virtual Machine Launcher", which says: "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit." When I dismiss that dialog I get another dialog containing information:

[info dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTawq.png)

I have Java 18.0.1.1 installed. The OS is Windows 10 Enterprise, version 21H2, OS build 19044.1766

Comment: `eclipse-java-indigo-win32-x86_64.zip` is not Eclipse 2022-06, but Eclipse Indigo, which was released more than a decade ago. [Eclipse 2022-06 can be downloaded here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

Comment: Also, in general, when you try to run a fresh installation of Eclipse you need to ensure that you have a JDK installed and that you have it configured in Eclipse's INI file.

Comment: @DavidConrad *Unless* it came with one, as many of the current downloads do.